# How to rotate around z axis only for many objects?

Tags: animation

I have around 100 objects and I will rotate them around z axis in animation. I tried add a keyframe for them but they rotate around XYZ by default. I have to manually uncheck XY axis.

Is there a way I can uncheck XY axis for my 100 objects in one run?

[image]

Comment: @moonboots, I am on Mac and I tried a few combiantions but they do not work. What's the name for this operation? No, around 1 Z axis.

Comment: oop sorry I forgot it was for a keyframe

Answer (score 2):

Use cmd + L and choose "link animation data".